Oracle Apex - group stacked barchart?
Is it possible to create a grouped stacked barchart in Oracle Apex?
I am a beginner when it comes to charts and I don't know how to group stacked bars. I tried to find a solution on my own and on google. Unfortunately I couldn't find an answer for this problem.
Could you help me please?


Have a look at the "Sample Charts" app that can be installed from the Gallery.

The "grouping" can be achieved using the "Stack Category" attribute which can also use column value (check help in the builder)

